# best way to determine if my_page is being loaded only by facebook

Tags: facebook, iframe, request, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

Is there a sure-fire way to determine if my_page is being loaded into an iframe of only facebook?

---

some techniques that partially help:

**A** (php) - the php $_REQUEST seems to have some implicit possibilities, but seems questionable since I believe it could be mimicked by other sites.

**B** (js) -  I can use js to do *(self == parent)* to determine if my_page is being loaded into a parent frame  ... but I cannot get anymore info than that. For instance, the url of the parent.

**C** (fb-jsSDK) -  The facebook javascript SDK gives me some info as to whether my_page is being loaded by a *logged in* user, but seems to be uninformative if loaded by a non-logged in user.

---

*IGY (and others): please do not trash my post ... if you know of a better place on the internet to ask this question, then tell me. Facebook advised developers to come here to ask questions.*

Answer (score 1):

I’d say the best way is to look for the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) parameter – when it is there *and* you have successfully verified it, then you can be sure that it is the intial load of your app into either a canvas or page tab iframe directly on Facebook.

(Verifying the signed_request requires your app secret, and only you and Facebook know that.)

Since you only get a `signed_request` on the initial load of your page, you should then put that info – *page has been called in an iframe on facebook.com* - into your session, so that you can look it up there on subsequent pages.

Comment: do you know if it is possible for another website, say pirate_site.com, to inject a fake 'signed_request' property into the $_REQUEST array ... thereby fooling my_site when it attempts to load it into its own iframe?

Comment: No, as I said, if you have __verified__ the request (see Step 2 on linked page), you can be sure it’s genuine – because it is signed using your app secret, and only you and Facebook know that.

Comment: to be honest I had never understood the app_secret thing ... could I request that you add that to your answer, since it seems to directly answer my question ???

Comment: What is still unclear to you after carefully reading the linked page …?

Comment: you have opened a can of worms with this: "carefully reading the linked (facebook) page" ... I find their documentation to be as stressful as any documentation that I have ever dealt with (12 years of computer work). But that is another subject, and I know that hardcore facebook developers love all things mark zukerburg, so it does me no good to get into that debate here:)

However, in the context of my question, and your explaining that the app_secret is the missing link, I now understand that!

Comment: CBroe, I would like to mark your response as the answer, as it does point in that direction ... currently it does not mention the app secret, however, which appears to be the key to answering my question ... Would you be kind enough to edit your comment to include "if you verify the signed_request with your app secret, pirate sites can't fool your app ... please see the link provided, Step2"